# ftp_login() : SSL/TLS handshake failed

Tags: php, ftps

I have to retrieve a file by using FTPS :

```
$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server, 9921, 10);

$bool = ftp_login($ftp, $login, $pass);

ftp_pasv($ftp, true);

$files = ftp_nlist($ftp, "/");

var_dump($files);
die();
```

But I have this warnings, and `$files` is **false**

```
Warning: ftp_login() [function.ftp-login]: SSL/TLS handshake failed in xxx\view.importfromadmin.php on line 81

Warning: ftp_login() [function.ftp-login]: Using authentication type TLS in xxx\view.importfromadmin.php on line 81
```

How can I fixe it ?

Comment: can you connect to the server using "lftp" program? (It's in CLI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can copy my file using this :

```
$ftp_path = "ftps://$ftp_login:$ftp_password@$ftp_server:9921/".$import_file;

copy($ftp_path, $uploadFileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this very same issue this week.

I was able to diagnose this by enumerating the OpenSSL errors obtained after `ftp_login` failed in this way:

```
$err = openssl_error_string();
while ($err)
{
    echo($err . "\n");
    $err = openssl_error_string();
}
```

Which gave me the following output:

> error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small
> error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init

And this output lead me to understand that my FTP server configuration (in my case `vsftpd`) was using a low-security cypher.

> The fix was to go into my `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file on the server and add `ssl_ciphers=HIGH` to the configuration.

Hopefully, this insight will be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is going to lay with OpenSSL not being compiled with PHP. You can find more information about that here: http://www.deciacco.com/blog/php/php-openssl-and-ftp_ssl_connect-on-win32

With information on how to fix it as well. You can check if your PHP has OpenSSL compiled through the `phpinfo`. Given that you are running a Windows server check the link above. Since you did not provide that information this is just a random guess.

Comment: OpenSSL is compiled and enabled on my server (Zend server)