# ftp_nlist(): data_accept: SSL/TLS handshake failed

Tags: php, ssl, ftp, ftps

Once upon a time, there was a normalish error in PHP land:

> Warning: ftp_nlist(): data_accept: SSL/TLS handshake failed in [path] on line 29

But here's the catch, "line 29" is not the connection or login, note how it referenced the `ftp_nlist()` function:

```
$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect($cred['host'], $cred['port'], 180);
if (!ftp_login($ftp, $cred['user'], $cred['pass'])) {die("Login Failed");}
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);

$files = ftp_nlist($ftp, '');
```

OpenSSL is compiled and enabled in `phpinfo()` as suggested here:
[ftp_login() : SSL/TLS handshake failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553681/ftp-login-ssl-tls-handshake-failed)

Other posts I've seen all seem to reference error in the `ftp_ssl_connect()` or `ftp_login()` commands which work for me. What can I check when `ftp_login()` returns true?

Or... are there any logs to get more details on what is wrong?

I'm using php 5.3.29. The code does work properly on my desktop (php 7), but I'm hoping I don't have to upgrade the server to 7 for this to work

12-28-2017 update:
Upgrading to 5.6 resolved, so looks like Martin is on point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ftp_nlist` opens a data connection. That connection needs TLS/SSL handshake too.

As the control connection handshake succeeded, the problem indeed cannot be with an absent TLS/SSL support in PHP. Neither the problem can be with anything like the server and PHP not being able to find a cipher to agree on.

When TLS/SSL handshake on data connection fails after handshake on control connection succeeded, it's quite usually because the client (PHP) did not reuse TLS/SSL session from control connection on the data connection (see [Why is session reuse useful in FTPS?](https://superuser.com/q/989048/213663)). Some servers do require that. PHP supports the reuse only since 5.6.26. See [PHP Bug 70195](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70195). So make sure you use that version of PHP at least.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is quite old, but in case someone else hits this problem:

If your `ftp_ssl_connect` and `ftp_login` works fine but functions like `ftp_nlist`, `ftp_put`, `ftp_fput` don't works the problem might be that your FTP server is using port `21` for Connection but different port ranges for data transfer, that explains why you can connect and login but you can't upload or download data, and you need to allow the Out-going connections to those port range in your firewall

Comment: Usually you would get "connection refused" or similar error in this scenario. As the firewall should not allow the handshake to even start. But ok, it might happen.

Comment: Yeah but in our case, the FTP server allowed connection and login, but not data transfer because it was using different ports

Comment: Sure, I understand that. I would expect "connection refused", when trying to open the data connection.