# ftp_nlist Cannot List Directories and files

Tags: php, ssl, curl

As part of my job, I need to develop a connection system to an FTP that uses `FTP, FTPS Explicit` and `FTPS Implicit` then list the folder tree in the server.

I don't have any problems with `FTP and FTPS Implicit` but I can't list directories in the `FTPS Explicit` case. The `ftp_nlist` function returns me false in all cases even using `ftp_pasv` after login.

I use Curl for the implicit and ftp_connect for the classic FTP. For the explicit I use `ftp_ssl_connect` and `ftp_login` which returns all 2 true. `ftp_nlist` works in the case of a classic ftp connection but not for the explicit one.

I am forced to use `PHP version 5.3` and I don't have the possibility to upgrade the version. Digging a bit, I found a bug statement that seems to be close to my concerns: [ftp_nlist(): data_accept: SSL/TLS handshake failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635241/ftp-nlist-data-accept-ssl-tls-handshake-failed)

My code:

```
$this->ftpStream = ftp_ssl_connect ($host, $port);
$this->ftpConnection = ftp_login ($this->ftpStream, $login, $password);
ftp_pasv($this->ftpStream, true);
$filesList = ftp_nlist($this->ftpStream, $directory);
```

Does anyone have a workaround (using curl maybe?)
thank you in advance

Comment: Having the same problem and afaik, upgrading PHP versions is the only way to fix this. From what I read, reuse of SSL sessions was added to 5.6.26 and 7.1, though I have yet to test this since I am still on an older 5.6 install

Answer (score 1):

With ftp function and PHP 5.4 i cannot use ftp_nlist.
So i make a function that did the same with CURL :

```
/**
     * Retourne la liste des fichiers et répertoires présent dans le dossier courant
     *
     * @return array Liste des fichiers et dossiers
     */
    public function getDirectoryContent()
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://' . $this->login . ':' . $this->password . '@' . $this->host . $this->directory);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->login . ':' . $this->password);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, true);
        $return = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if ($return === false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $return, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retourne la liste des fichiers et répertoires présent dans le dossier courant avec les informations sur les fichiers
     *
     * @return array Liste des fichiers et dossiers
     */
    public function getDetailsDirectoryContent()
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://' . $this->login . ':' . $this->password . '@' . $this->host . $this->directory);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->login . ':' . $this->password);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'LIST');
        $return = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if ($return === false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $fichiers = array();
            $nbFichiers = 0;
            if (preg_match_all(
                '/([-dl])([rwxst-]{9})[ ]+([0-9]+)[ ]+([^ ]+)[ ]+(.+)[ ]+([0-9]+)[ ]+([a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[0-9]+)[ ]+([0-9:]+)[ ]+(.*)/',
                $return, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
                foreach ($m as $f) {
                    $fichiers[$nbFichiers] = array();
                    $fichiers[$nbFichiers]['dir']         = $f[1] == 'd';  // Répertoire ?
                    $fichiers[$nbFichiers]['filename']    = $f[9];         // Nom
                    $fichiers[$nbFichiers]['size']        = $f[6];         // Taille
                    $fichiers[$nbFichiers]['owner']       = $f[4];         // Propriétaire
                    $fichiers[$nbFichiers]['group']       = $f[5];         // Groupe
                    $fichiers[$nbFichiers]['permissions'] = $f[2];         // Permissions
                    $fichiers[$nbFichiers]['mtime']       = "$f[7] $f[8]"; // Date de dernière modification
                    $nbFichiers++;
                }
            }
            return $fichiers;
        }
    }
```